# How do I wrap till a predefined parent for multiple elements in cheerio or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cheerio

I've got a similar xml:

```
<document>
   <paragraph>
      <a>
         <b>
            <c>
               <d>text1</d>
            </c>
         </b>
      </a>
   </paragraph>
   <paragraph>
      <a>
         <b>
            <c>
               <d>text2</d>
            </c>
         </b>
      </a>
   </paragraph>
</document>
```

There's obviously more paragraphs, etc.

Using cheerio (jquery's syntax applies too) I want to wrap the `d` element till it has only `paragraph` as parent.

```
<document>
   <paragraph>
       <d>text1</d>
   </paragraph>
   <paragraph>
       <d>text2</d>
   </paragraph>
</document>
```

I thought about using the `.unwrap()` command 3 times on the element. But I have no guarantee that in some xml between `d` and `paragraph` I may have a smaller or bigger number of parents.

Comment: Can you post the resulting HTML/XML that you're expecting?

Comment: Done, I totally forgot. Thank you for the help with formatting as well.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will work in your environment, but, i think you could use idea:

```
$('d').each(function() {
cloned=$(this).clone();

$(this).closest('paragraph').append(cloned);
$(this).parentsUntil($('paragraph')).remove();

});
```

So, clone element, place it inside paragraph, remove all `parentsUntil()` paragraph...

Demo:

```js
$('d').each(function() {
cloned=$(this).clone();

$(this).closest('paragraph').append(cloned);
$(this).parentsUntil($('paragraph')).remove();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<document>
   <paragraph>
      <a>
         <b>
            <c>
               <d>text1</d>
            </c>
         </b>
      </a>
   </paragraph>
   <paragraph>
      <a>
         <b>
            <c>
               <d>text2</d>
            </c>
         </b>
      </a>
   </paragraph>
</document>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution [**DEMO**](http://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=00eab744b1c2319eec51f8b7664869ea). I used for loop to clone the `<d>` element and then rewrite it into the paragraph element.

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var i = $('d').length;
  for(x=i--;x>=0;x--){
    var c = $('d').eq(x).clone();
    $('d').eq(x).parents('paragraph').html(c);
  }
});
```

Comment: Heh, basically, same idea... :)

Comment: Ah yes saw yours now,  same logic =)